# What types of dates are these?

Tags: ios, date, format

I have a plist with this format date:

```
Mar 11, 2013 10:16:31 AM
```

which shows up in my console as

```
2013-03-11 16:16:31 +0000
```

whereas a webservice is returning something that in the console looks like this:

```
2013-03-01T18:21:45.231Z
```

How do I fix my plist date to the same format as the web service?

Comment: The first (oops, second) form is what you get if you print an NSDate with `%@` formatting.  The second (oops, third) is a character string.  You can use NSDateFormatter to format an NSDate to match your other style, if you so desire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your three date formats:

1. The first is just the date format when you look at a `NSDate` in a plist in Xcode, a human readable date in the current locale (but if you look at the plist in a text editor, you'll see it's actually written in `@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"` format).
2. The second is the default formatting from the `description` method a `NSDate` (e.g. you `NSLog` a `NSDate`).
3. The third is [RFC 3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt)/[ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format (with fractions of a second), often used in web services.

See Apple's [Technical Q&A QA1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html).

As an aside, that Technical Note doesn't include the milliseconds, so you might want to use something like `@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'"`, for example:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.locale = enUSPOSIXLocale;
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'";
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
```

You can use this if you want to store the date as a string in RFC 3339/ISO 8601 format in the plist (or alternatively, if you need to convert a `NSDate` to a string for transmission to your web service). As noted above, the default plist format does not preserve fractions of a second for `NSDate` objects, so if that's critical, storing dates as strings as generated by the above code can be useful.

And this date formatter can be used for converting dates to strings (using `stringFromDate`), as well as converting properly formatting strings to `NSDate` objects (using `dateFromString`).

Comment: Note that dates retain their fractional parts when written using the binary format (`NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0`).